# using sprites as background image for input fields without accidentally show other parts of the sprite

Tags: css, css-sprites

From something like a fancy calendar control where you want to use an image of a calendar as an icon on the right side of an input box, what would be the best approach to use a sprite in this scenario?

We currently have a sprite setup with this calendar icon, but when the input field grows in width, it starts showing other parts of the sprite.

The Pseudo option won't work here since pseudo doesn't work on non-container elements.

Comment: Looks like no-one's worked with this before?